# Is it possible to speed up this mean autocorrelation calculation in numpy using vectorization?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, autocorrelation

I am looking to speed-up the following mean autocorrelation code that uses standard autocorrelation function in numpy. Is it possible to vectorize this?

input: X -> shape(100,3000) = 100 day time series of 3000 items

output: float -> find the mean(across the 3000 items) of the lag5 autocorrelation of each item

```
import numpy as np
import time
A = np.random.rand(100,3000)
start_time = time.time()
np.nanmean(np.array([np.corrcoef(np.array([A[:-5,i],A[5:,i]]))[1,0] for i in range(A.shape[1])]),axis=0)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

--- 0.35528588 seconds ---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mainly care about smaller runtime and less so about how it is achieved. The following approach achieves a more than 3x speedup by improving the calculations of the correlation coefficients.

More specifically, it replaces calls to `np.corrcoef` with calls to a custom function `fast_corrcoef`. In essence, `fast_corrcoef` follows the numpy approach for calculating the correlation coefficient, except it does not perform a lot of the redundant computation. Mainly, it exploits the fact that for each call of `np.corrcoef`, which calls `np.cov` to compute the covariance matrix, which requires computing the average of both series `S[:-lag]` and `S[lag:]`, does a lot of unneccessary computation: Instead of computing the averages separately as in `np.cov`, `fast_corrcoef` computes them by first calculating the sum of `S[lag:-lag]` and then calculating the averages of the two series using that intermediate sum. For time series of size `n`, this yields only `(n - 2 * lag) + 2 * lag + 2 = n + 2` additions as opposed to `2n` additions, i.e. essentially saving `50%` of all additions for computing the average, in case of `A.shape = (100, 3000)` and `lag = 5` amounting to `(2 * (100 - 5) - (100 - 5 + 2)) * 3000 = 279000` saved additions.

Further, since the covariance matrix is symmetric, a full matrix multiplication when calculating it is not required and thus the call to `np.dot` as the case with `np.cov` has also been replaced by an expression which does only the tree vector dot products that are actually necessary, i.e. calculates the covariance only once instead of twice.

```
import numpy as np
import time


def fast_corrcoef(X, lag):
    n = X.shape[1]
    mid_sum = X[0, lag:].sum()
    X -= np.array([(mid_sum + X[0, :lag].sum()) / n, (mid_sum + X[1, -lag:].sum()) / n])[:, None]
    return (X[0,:] * X[1,:]).sum() / (np.sqrt((X[0,:] ** 2).sum()) * np.sqrt((X[1,:] ** 2).sum()))
    
A = np.random.rand(100,3000)

lag = 5

def orig(A):
    return np.nanmean(np.array([np.corrcoef(np.array([A[:-5,i],A[5:,i]]))[1,0] for i in range(A.shape[1])]),axis=0)

def faster(A, lag):
    corrcoefs = np.empty([A.shape[1]])
    for i in range(A.shape[1]):
        corrcoefs[i] = fast_corrcoef(np.array([A[:-lag, i], A[lag:, i]]), lag)
    return np.nanmean(corrcoefs, axis=0)

start_time = time.time()
res_orig = orig(A)
runtime_orig = time.time() - start_time
print(f'orig: runtime: {runtime_orig:.4f}s; result: {res_orig}')


start_time = time.time()
res_faster = faster(A, lag)
runtime_faster = time.time() - start_time
print(f'fast: runtime: {runtime_faster:.4f}s; result: {res_faster}')

assert abs(res_orig - res_faster) < 1e-16

speedup = runtime_orig / runtime_faster

print(f'speedup: {speedup:.4f}x')
```

This code printed the following (when I ran it in Google Colab):

```
orig: runtime: 0.4214s; result: -0.00961872402216293
fast: runtime: 0.1138s; result: -0.009618724022162932
speedup: 3.7030x
```

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution and for the detailed explanation.
A related question - if I wanted to find the correlation over two lags (say lag=5 as well as lag=1), can functions faster(A, lag) and fast_corrcoef(X, lag) be modified to get even more speed up versus calling faster() twice? i.e. faster(A,5); faster(A,1)

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Also, if this is run multiple times for non-fixed time intervals (regardless of lag) at once (i.e. using windows of the data), one could exploit the same principles for additional speedup.

Comment: @MichaelHodel How can I adapt this just to compute the autocorrelation of a 1D vector? I have some vector of length n, and would like an output of length n, so no averaging.